# How to project a Mongo LINQ query to only return child object from document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, parent-child

I have a structure like:

```
Client
    ClientId
    Name
    Address
    ...etc...
    Asset[]
        AssetId
        name
        Enabled
```

I want to get all Asset at ounce as a Asset object and not get all Client and then filter to get the Asset (because mu client object has 50 properties... some big arrays).

I endd up with:

```
    var filter = Builders<Client>.Filter.Eq("Id", clientId);

    var u = _coll.Find(filter)
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(w=> w.Id == clientId)
                    .SelectMany(ss=> ss.Asset);
```

This is doing what I dont want to do, I am getting the full client object and then filtering... I tried all things like unwind, Project, etc... couldn't make any to work.

How can I get the Asset in the fastest way and clean way possible. I would like only to fetch the data I need, so brind the client is not a option..

thanks.

Comment: FYI: [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats: [tag] [tag] [question title] [tag] [tag] [tag]"_

Answer (score 0):

this is quite simple with MongoDAL, which is a convenient wrapper for the c# driver. see the code below for my approach.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDAL;

namespace Example
{
    class Client : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Asset[] Assets { get; set; }
    }

    class Asset
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("assets");

            var client = new Client
            {
                Name = "Marco Polo",
                Assets = new Asset[]
                 {
                     new Asset{ Name = "asset one", Enabled = true},
                     new Asset{ Name = "asset two", Enabled = true},
                     new Asset{ Name = "asset three", Enabled = true}
                 }
            };

            client.Save();

            var clientID = client.ID;

            var result = client.Collection()
                               .Where(c => c.ID == clientID)
                               .SelectMany(c => c.Assets)
                               .ToArray();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

generated mongo query:

```
aggregate([{ 
"$match" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0643744effe2fa482648e") } },
{ "$unwind" : "$Assets" },
{ "$project" : 
{ "Assets" : "$Assets", "_id" : 0 } }])
```